# What is regular expression pattern for barcode result specific format in c#

Tags: c#, regex

My barcode results has following format

**ASD-[three capital charater]-[number]**

```
e.g. ASD-AAA-0001
     ASD-BBB-99999
```

How can I test this result with regex in .net c#. Please help me. Thanks alot.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself?  We usually prefer that you show some effort and research before posting a question.

Comment: Actually I only knows testing character and number only limitation and I want to know for specific pattern. can you share reference for specific pattern in regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is `^ASD-[A-Z]{3}-\d+`.
I recommend start learning regex by reading online tutorials. I personally used this : http://regexone.com/

Comment: Technically the regex here is wrong. It will accept zero or more digits at the end of the pattern, whereas in the examples cited one or more digits are required. e.g. This will accept `ASD-AAA-` as valid. Also, it is not anchored to the start of input, so `8734954ASD-AAA-huishdfiu` is also accepted. I suggest that you anchor the pattern to the start and end of the input, and accept 1 or more digits using `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 3):

As for the regular expression itself, you could try something like this:

```
^ASD-[A-Z]{3}-\d+$
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm for a straightforward tutorial on using regular expressions in C#. You will want to use the `Regex.IsMatch(string input, string pattern)` method, some examples:

```
csharp> String pattern = @"^ASD-[A-Z]{3}-\d+$";
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AAA-0001", pattern);    
true
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AA-0001", pattern);  
false
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AAA-1", pattern);   
true
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AAA-1A", pattern);
false
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("  ASD-AAA-1", pattern); 
false
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AAA-1", pattern);   
true
csharp> Regex.IsMatch("ASD-AAA-", pattern);
false
```